# Showing and hiding text on more than one place on a website by clicking a single link

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show and hide content on a webpage by clicking a link 'Click for More text'. While this works fine, my intention is to display more text in two places on the page at the same time.

How can I 'unhide' and hide two different div id's by one click?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
      item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    }
}
</script>
```

and the HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:unhide(‘content’);”>Click for More text</a>

<div id=“content” class="hidden">
hi
</div>

<div id=“content2” class="hidden">
how can i display this from the same link..?
</div>
```

Comment: Since `id`s must be unique, why not try hiding based on a `class` common to all of the divs instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them in one more div to wrap it and then show just that one

```
<a href="javascript:unhide(‘content_wrapper’);”>Click for More text</a>

<div id="content_wrapper" class="hidden">
  <div id=“content”>
     hi
  </div>

  <div id=“content2”>
    how can i display this from the same link..?
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are using jQuery, better idea would be to use classes, check the code below for example

HTML:

```
<button onclick="unhide('more_info')">
   Click for More text
</button>

<div class="more_info hidden">
  hi
</div>

<div class="more_info hidden">
  how can i display this from the same link..?
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function unhide (arg) {
   // toggle class, or remove or add, what ever you need
   $('.'+ arg).toggleClass('hidden');
}
```

EDIT:

To answer question posted by OP in comments.
When it comes to jQuery, most people use only couple of forms of selectors. You can visit [this link to find out more about selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

For the basics, you are mostly going to be using 2 forms. Personally I use class selector in most cases which is `'.selector'`

What you can do with it means you use it in form of `$('.classSelector')` where classSelector can be any class you want to select.

Couple of examples

```
<div id="test-div-id" class="test-div-class">
  <p class="paragraph paragraph-1">This is first</p>
  <p class="paragraph paragraph-2">This is second</p>
  <p class="paragraph paragraph-3">This is third</p>
</div>
```

For javascript, you can then use following

```
$('.test-div-class')
// returns the div by selecting it's class

$('#test-div-id')
// returns the div by selecting it's ID
```

So if you wanted to check the value of first paragraph you could do

```
$('.paragraph-1').html();
// returns 'This is first'
```

You can also select multiple things, let's say you want to hide all paragraphs, you could use `.hide()` function from jQuery.

```
$('.paragraph').hide();
// the selector returns collection of all nodes containing class 'paragraph'
// after that we apply function hide.
```

The last one works on all classes, so you could mix paragraphs and divs and spans and what not. That brings us to next selector, by type

```
$('p').hide();
// this selector will return every paragraph by type selection
```

And you can also use what I did in the answer, simple adding of strings

```
$('.paragraph-1').html();
// returns 'This is first'

var selectorAsAnVariable = 'paragraph-1';

$(selectorAsAnVariable).html();
// returns nothing since it didn't select anything
// this is same as writing $('paragraph-1').html() which would be type selection
// since you don't have type paragraph-1 it fails

$(.selectorAsAnVariable).html();
// this fails on syntax error because unexpected token

$('.selectorAsAnVariable').html();
// returns nothing since it didn't select anything
// this is because you would be trying to select elements which really have that class


$('.'+selectorAsAnVariable).html();
// returns 'This is first'
// this is because this is same as $('.'+'paragraph-1').html()
// which is same as $('.paragraph-1').html() which we know is an class selector
```

You can also mix them, but I would advise against it because of performance issues, code readability and other reasons, for example you can target div by class and filter paragraph-1 from there. But in most cases it is better to write your code in way that you can avoid that.

For more about the topic, check the link I provided. Also you can use the search to look for other function explanations there.

I hope this clarified things a bit :)

Comment: Thank you. What I failed to explain, is that the second class "content2" could be anywhere on the site. There could be any code between "content1" and "content2", and seeing them would be triggered from the one link. Therefore the first option won't help as it closes the div. But I see that using jQuery would allow this?

Comment: Yes, you can use jQuery to get this archive easier since it can work with classes really nicely. You could get without jQuery as well, but would be easier to start with and then later you can explore other options.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! As I was doing this with Wordpress, it took a while to figure that instead of "$('.'+ arg).toggleClass('hidden');" one needs to use        "jQuery('.'+ arg).toggleClass('hidden');"

Comment: I will edit my answer to include it with better formating